# Numpy sort much slower than Matlab sort

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, openmp

I am turning some codes from Matlab to Python. I am sometimes quite surprised by the performance loss. Here is an example on sorting arrays, which turns me nuts.

**Matlab :**

```matlab
a=rand(50000,1000);tic;b=sort(a,1);toc
```

*Elapsed time is 0.624460 seconds.*

**Python :**

```python
import numpy as np
import time
a=np.random.rand(50000,1000);
t0=time.time();b=np.sort(a,axis=0);print(time.time()-t0)
```

*4.192200422286987*

Can someone explain why there is a factor 7 in performance for such a basic operation? I see that sort is not multi-threaded on Python and this should be the main reason on my 20 cores machine.

For now I tried (following [this link](https://docs.anaconda.com/mkl-optimizations/index.html)):

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install intel-mkl-full
conda install -c intel numpy
```

But this did not change the behavior. In a terminal I also typed

```bash
export MKL_NUM_THREADS=20
export NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS=20
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=20
```

In Python, the following command

```python
np.show_config()
```

returns

```
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/pierre/anaconda3/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/pierre/anaconda3/include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/pierre/anaconda3/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/pierre/anaconda3/include']
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/pierre/anaconda3/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/pierre/anaconda3/include']
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/pierre/anaconda3/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/pierre/anaconda3/include']
```

Which seems to indicate that I am really using MKL. Is there a way to have np.sort work in parallel for arrays?

Comment: Here's one important thing to note: numpy uses **row-major** order whereas matlab uses **column-major** order for storing data in memory (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order). You are sorting across the vertical axis, which naturally favors matlab since all numbers are stored contiguous. I executed the python code twice, once with axis=0 which took 4.24s and once with axis=1 which took 2.33s.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comment. This is an important remark, but this does not seem to explain the behavior. I tried with square arrays and sorting along both axes and the difference is still about the same. Parallelization is the thing by monitoring the core activities.

Comment: It would also be more fair to use the exact same dataset for each, you appear to be generating random datasets which are different in each case.

Comment: @Wolfie Fair point, but since P. Weiss essentially sorts 50k uniform random numbers a thousand times, I think this should "average out" any unfavorable random effects.

Comment: Given that Matlab's `sort` is a compiled and therefore obfuscated function, nobody outside of the MathWorks engineering team will be able to answer this, therefore I don't think this can't be answered other than in an opinion-based way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a few hours and checking with colleagues, the solution is now clear:

**np.sort *is not multi-threaded and there is no way to accelerate it.***

It suffices to look at the sources to check this:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/main/numpy/core/src/npysort

For such an important function, it is surprising to me. Like 99.9% of the codes using sorting with np could be accelerated. I guess that I will implement my own sorting function with Cython.

Best,

Pierre

Comment: You might want to check out the `parallel_sort` python package: https://pypi.org/project/parallel-sort/

Comment: Thanks again to point out this nice information! I tried already, but this only works for 1D arrays. I opened an issue in the numpy github https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/20575 to see if anyone is motivated to improve it :).

Comment: Allow me to add this: When parallelizing code, you can distinguish between *task parallelism* and *data parallelism*. Task parallelism would be to distribute single columns (or rows) of your matrix to a worker and each worker will sort it. Data parallelism would mean that you distribute a single row (or column) to many workers and they will use a divide and conquer approach to sort it. Task parallelism sould work with `parallel_sort`. Performance obviously depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for this information. It seems that Matlab parallelizes in both directions. On its side np.sort parallelizes in no direction. I could probably use numba and parallel_sort jointly, but this is a bit ugly. For now, I am using cupy.sort, which is working super nicely. The only problem is that for my problem I need to switch from CPU to GPU at every iterations, losing a lot of time in data transfers.